# How to make additional library directories relative?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am using Visual Studio to add some additional library directories. However the directories added are absolute paths, I am wondering how to make it relative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to take full use of **`Macros`** that are related to your Visual Studio project/solution. Particularly, you want to use `$(SolutionDir)` and `$(ProjectDir)`. For example, if the library is located under your solution folder named `libFolder`, then you can just add the following path to your library directories (`Include`/`Library`/...)

```
$(SolutionDir)\libFolder
```

---

**Further reading**: check out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx) to see more info about Visual Studio macros.

Answer (score 1):

From your current project path you can use below:

Project Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library directories

```
..\..\Folder\Lib;
```